# Sebp/elk not running on docker with error

Tags: elasticsearch, docker, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

**hello all engineering on the world
Im 1 problem to after install ELK stack on docker
my infrastructure:
1- Windows 10 New Creators Update
2- my laptop model: N552VX (8Gig RAM)
3- docker toolbox without prerequisites = sample java machine and more ...
and install sebp/elk on terminal docker with command : $ docker pull sebp/elk
installation successfully and not running --- > An error was pointed out that a number of errors
SEE FULL ERROR == http://textuploader.com/d99r1
Plz check error !**

```
bootstrap checks failed
max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]
[2017-05-12T08:47:16,687][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [Zn8_vUw] stopping ...
[2017-05-12T08:47:16,721][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [Zn8_vUw] stopped
[2017-05-12T08:47:16,721][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [Zn8_vUw] closing ...
[2017-05-12T08:47:16,749][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [Zn8_vUw] closed
[2017-05-12T09:36:39,466][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [] initializing ...
[2017-05-12T09:36:39,746][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [Zn8_vUw] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/var/lib/elasticsearch (c/Users)]], net usable_space [87.9gb], net total_space [118.6gb], spins? [possibly], types [vboxsf]
[2017-05-12T09:36:39,750][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [Zn8_vUw] heap size [1.9gb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
[2017-05-12T09:36:39,760][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] node name [Zn8_vUw] derived from node ID [Zn8_vUwXTyGl4E35KOKo5Q]; set [node.name] to override
[2017-05-12T09:36:39,761][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] version[5.4.0], pid[71], build[780f8c4/2017-04-28T17:43:27.229Z], OS[Linux/4.4.66-boot2docker/amd64], JVM[Oracle Corporation/OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM/1.8.0_121/25.121-b13]
[2017-05-12T09:36:42,884][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [Zn8_vUw] loaded module [aggs-matrix-stats]
[2017-05-12T09:36:42,885][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [Zn8_vUw] loaded module [ingest-common]
[2017-05-12T09:36:42,885][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [Zn8_vUw] loaded module [lang-expression]
[2017-05-12T09:36:42,885][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [Zn8_vUw] loaded module [lang-groovy]
[2017-05-12T09:36:42,885][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [Zn8_vUw] loaded module [lang-mustache]
[2017-05-12T09:36:42,885][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [Zn8_vUw] loaded module [lang-painless]
[2017-05-12T09:36:42,885][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [Zn8_vUw] loaded module [percolator]
[2017-05-12T09:36:42,885][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [Zn8_vUw] loaded module [reindex]
[2017-05-12T09:36:42,885][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [Zn8_vUw] loaded module [transport-netty3]
[2017-05-12T09:36:42,886][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [Zn8_vUw] loaded module [transport-netty4]
[2017-05-12T09:36:42,887][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [Zn8_vUw] no plugins loaded
[2017-05-12T09:36:50,337][INFO ][o.e.d.DiscoveryModule    ] [Zn8_vUw] using discovery type [zen]
[2017-05-12T09:36:52,802][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] initialized
[2017-05-12T09:36:52,803][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [Zn8_vUw] starting ...
[2017-05-12T09:36:53,754][INFO ][o.e.t.TransportService   ] [Zn8_vUw] publish_address {172.17.0.2:9300}, bound_addresses {0.0.0.0:9300}
[2017-05-12T09:36:53,792][INFO ][o.e.b.BootstrapChecks    ] [Zn8_vUw] bound or publishing to a non-loopback or non-link-local address, enforcing bootstrap checks
[2017-05-12T09:36:53,816][ERROR][o.e.b.Bootstrap          ] [Zn8_vUw] node validation exception
bootstrap checks failed
max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]
[2017-05-12T09:36:53,840][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [Zn8_vUw] stopping ...
[2017-05-12T09:36:53,932][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [Zn8_vUw] stopped
[2017-05-12T09:36:53,932][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [Zn8_vUw] closing ...
[2017-05-12T09:36:53,998][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [Zn8_vUw] closed
```

**and installing with Guide : http://elk-docker.readthedocs.io/
Will guide me so that I can have a elk stack ?**

Comment: You can try a version less than 5.

Comment: thanks;
Why should a version less than 5?

Comment: I do not know - just met this issue recently.Maybe something wrong with docker image configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Try using docker compose

docker-compose.yml

```
elk:
  image: sebp/elk
  ports:
    - "5601:5601"
    - "9200:9200"
    - "5044:5044"
  environment:
    - ELASTICSEARCH_USER=elastic
    - ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD=s0m3C0mpl3xP@ssw0rd!
    - LOGSTASH_USER=elastic
    - LOGSTASH_PASSWORD=s0m3C0mpl3xP@ssw0rd!
    - KIBANA_USER=kibana
    - KIBANA_PASSWORD=s0m3C0mpl3xP@ssw0rd!

$ docker-compose up -d elk
```

Source : https://medium.com/@gchandra/easy-way-setup-elk-on-docker-10938f3fcf96

Answer (score 1):

As error showing that **max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]**

so you need to increase memory by running below command

> vm.max_map_count = 262144

and run it again